# How do I make my object move towards another object (or point) in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, artificial-intelligence

Hello I am wondering how I would make an `object` move towards another `object` or `point`. Down here is a tick method which is set to update 60 times a second. It's just a basic thing which moves based on the change in `x` and `y`.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

```
public void tick() {
    x += dX;
    y += dY;

    if(y <= 16 || y >= Game.HEIGHT-62) velY *= -1;
    if(x <= 16 || x >= Game.WIDTH-39) velX *= -1;

    collision();
}
```

Comment: Something like [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784303/java-move-image-towards-mouse-position/26791886#26791886)?

Comment: Well yes, but i'm not sure how to implement that into my code. Right now I am playing around with different mathematical alogrithms but they don't seem to be working. This example seems a bit confusing because it does not directly answer my question. If you can could you show me how it should look in my code? Also if you too are confused, I am trying to have an enemy (which the tick method is a part of) follow the user.

Comment: Oh, it does, it allows one object to move towards another, it just so happens that one of the objects is the mouse.  The magic happens instead the `ActionListener` of the `Timer`, `imagePosition.x += mousePoint.x < centerX ? -1 : 1;` when the x positions are not equal. Can you explain how the linked example doesn't answer your question...

Comment: OK, sorry my fault for being confused, I misunderstood the code, but I'm actually wondering how to make it smooth where the object will move in a straight line toward the object instead of just omnidirectionally

Comment: It depends on what you mean by straight line.  The linked example essentially creates a beeline straight for the mouse.  You could draw a line between the image and mouse and the image would walk it.