# Animation doesn't work, component just moves along the x axis

Tags: java, animation, awt

I'm trying to make an Agar.io simulation, so I'm using MouseMotionListener's mouseMoved method to find the cursor's location, and calculating the difference between the cursor's coordinates and agar's coordinates to calculate the slope for the animation.
Below is the code for the implemented mouseMoved():

```
private class CursorTracker implements MouseMotionListener {
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        //cursor location
        cursor_x = e.getPoint().getX();
        cursor_y = e.getPoint().getY();

        //agar location
        agar_x = agar.getX();
        agar_y = agar.getY();

        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Below is actionPerformed() for the panel's timer:

```
private class Animator implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //adding food
        if (count == 30) {
            addRandomFood();
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;

        //agar animation - functions on slope animation: x changes by 1, y by m
        double delta_x = cursor_x - agar_x;
        double delta_y = cursor_y - agar_y;

        //slope
        double m = (delta_y)/(delta_x);

        //pass parameters
        agar.move(1, m);

        repaint();
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the Agar.move() method:

```
public void move(double x_interval, double y_interval) {
    if (x >= 0)
        x -= x_interval;
    if (y >= 0)
        y -= y_interval;
}
```

My intention is to find out the slope (which is ∆y/∆x), change x by 1 and y by the slope (m) value at every timer's repeat, which should theoretically result in the agar object moving towards the cursor location bit by bit. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Also, the cursor detector (mouseMoved) seems to work weirdly; it works only once, agar doesn't change motion direction even the cursor is relocated. And it might even be not properly "listening" to the cursor and just doing it by default because regardless of the cursor's location when the program starts running, the agar always ends up moving along the x-axis towards the origin.

Comment: It would make more sense to try and calculate a "path following" algorithm, where you create a line between the current position of the object and the mouse and have the object follow the line

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603615/moving-an-image-to-the-position-of-the-cursor-where-is-clicked-on-a-jframe/43604224#43604224) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784303/java-move-image-towards-mouse-position/26791886#26791886)

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would this work? Wouldn't it still be the same algorithm as the slope method though?

Comment: Not really, as the x/y deltas would be different based on the amount of time the object has been following the path